# I have an web app registered in azure AD, How can I redirect to another website(password protected) after signing in?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, webapi

EX - 'https://example1.com' is the url of the azure AD registered app. When I sign in using Azure authentication, i want to be redirected to another website('https://example2.com') by bypassing the websites signing in. How to accomplish that? Do i need to register the new website to azure AD as well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the **redirect URL** after the user logs in to the application? You can set the redirect URL in Azure.

[image]

Comment: The redirect url site has to be registered in azure ad under same tenant?